# Is there a way to stop inline video clips from playing on MacOS Safari?

Tags: macos, safari, safari-extensions, configuration-profiles

My question applies to the desktop version of Safari, either as proper content (for example, supporting a news story) or inline video ads. The [iOS/iPadOS version of this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/374237/is-there-a-way-to-stop-inline-video-clips-from-playing-on-mobile-safari) doesn’t work for desktop Safari.

Is there a way on macOS to disable auto play of video?

Answer (score 2):

Found on Apple Communities : [Stop auto play HTML5 in Safari?](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7681448?start=0&tstart=0)

> Open Terminal and enter this command:
>   `defaults write com.apple.Safari IncludeInternalDebugMenu 1`
>
> That will unhide Safari's "Debug" menu.  Under that menu, go to Media
>   Flags, and then select Disallow Inline Video.   This will stop videos
>   from automatically playing when a page loads.

Just tested on Facebook - works.

Answer (score 1):

On macOS, you can disable inline media. This can be achieved by setting the preference manually, by quitting Safari and using the following:

```
defaults write com.apple.Safari WebKitMediaPlaybackAllowsInline -bool false
```

<sup>If you are using Safari Technology Preview, replace ‘Safari’ with ‘SafariTechnologyPreview’.</sup>

Alternatively, you can enable the debug menu and choose the option from there.

1. Quit Safari and enable the debug menu:

   ```
   defaults write com.apple.Safari IncludeInternalDebugMenu 1
   ```
2. Choose Debug → Media Flags → Disallow Inline Video.

   [image]

---

On iOS, this is not possible.

Comment: Just a note, the Debug also disables things you may want to see, such as YouTube. Took me a week to figure out why it wouldn't work, then I remembered toggling this.