# Is there a way to stop inline video clips from playing on mobile Safari?

Tags: ios, safari, safari-extensions, configuration-profiles, ipados

This question applies to the mobile versions of Safari, either as proper content (for example, supporting a news story) or inline video ads. Mobile means iPadOS and iOS on the iPhone and iPad. The [macOS version of this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/285389/is-there-a-way-to-stop-inline-video-clips-from-playing-on-safari) doesn’t provide mobile solutions.

Is there a way to disable auto play of video using a setting, configuration profile or third party app/content blocker?

Answer (score 0):

There's a quite straightforward way to do this now.

Simply go to **Settings > Accessibility > Motion** and turn off **Auto-Play Video Previews**.

[image]